# Find Vector in set A furthest from any Vector in set B

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Given 2 sets of Vectors in 3 dimensional space: A and B, what are the fastest algorithms to find the vector in set A furthest from any in set B?

Comment: If A=B, this is sometimes known as the "furthest point problem" or the problem of computing the diameter of a set of points.  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524715/781723, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276488/781723, and many other resources I'm sure you can find by searching on that term.  Perhaps looking at those methods will suggest something you can use for your version of the problem as well.